# Why is my Unity game being on Free Aspect after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello community I am having issue with the resolution, I set with canvas scaler and it has not any problems but when I build it the resolution just changes into Free Aspect, help me please. Already tried with Edit > delete all PlayerPrefs and deleting the registry file. The first image is Unity Connect 5 and the second one is when I build it. Unity version is 2020.01

[image]

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdTms.png)[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas scaler's `UI Scale Mode` is probably on `Constant Pixel Size`,
You should configure it to scale properly to match the width and height of the device using the reference resolution

[image]

Comment: Not only this, but make sure everything's fine in Edit -> Project Settings -> Whatever platform you're on -> Resolution and Presentation.

Comment: Hello Tenretni and Eric I just setted it with Canvas Scaler Mode matching by its Width and Height, depending of the UI I pot different values one by matching it in Width or Height uploaded images.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the orientation of your game in **Player Setting** by click **Edit ->
Project Setting -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation -> Orientation**. If Landscape is your prefer you can uncheck Portrait option and your game will run in Landscape.

Comment: Hello I have setted as portrait 1080 x 1920 but it builds as free aspect

Comment: @hello Can you take a picture of your Canvas Scaler setting and your Player Setting?

Comment: I just uploaded the player settings and Canvas settings

Comment: @hello I think your game is in Portrait so you should make your screen math with width instead of height.

Comment: yeah it's Portrait and I setted it all of them with width height 0 but nothing still building like Free Aspect